# Oracle Database Query Design

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I am currently working on a program that is supposed to predict the outcomes of a 1v1 contest.  I have given each player their own elo score and am collecting all sorts of data in order to predict who the winner would be.

For each fighter, I want to collect the **current** average elo of people that they are defeating as well as the **current** average elo of people that are defeating them.  Below is some sample data and explanations in order to help you better understand the data structure.

[image: Basic Stats Snapshot]

The picture above shows the basic stats view, V_FIGHT_REVIEW that simplifies my fights table for stats collection.  FID is the unique fight id and identifies the fight.  PID is the player id and identifies each unique player.  The WINNER column represents the winner of the fight.  So if PID is not equal to WINNER, that player did not win the fight.

[image: Player Table Snapshot]

This picture represents the PLAYERS table.  To the left you will recognize the PID for each player.  To the right you will see the column named ELO.

To rephrase the question, I am having trouble figuring out how I can produce the current average elo of each player they have defeated and the current average elo of each player that has defeated them.  These average elos should change as their opponents win/lose fights.  The output should be similar to below:

PID | AVG_ELO_DEF | AVG_ELO_DEF_BY

Comment: just to make sure, your doubt is about how to calculate elo or how to calculate averages? this phrase "These average elos should change as their opponents win/lose fights" confused me because that's what's elo is all about. The winner "takes" points from the loser

Comment: Say that player1 defeated player2.  Player2's elo would go into Player1's average defeated elo list as part of the average.  Just for simplicity, let's say that Player2 is the only one in Player1's list.  If Player2 then loses a game, Player2's elo will go down.  This would mean that Player1's Average Elo Defeated would go down also.

Comment: I think the confusion here is about the term "average ELO". You know, each player has only 1 ELO value. It's like a current score. To have an average ELO of one player, you should have different ELO values for it (distributed on time maybe) to calculate AVG. So there's no average ELO. Or there is?

Comment: or maybe I am missing something

Comment: I find it hard to explain also.  You are correct when you say that each player has only 1 elo.  But, when player1 defeats player2 and player2 has an elo of 1200, player1's Average_elo_defeated would be 1200.  If player1 goes on to defeat player3 who has an elo of 1000, Player1's Average_elo_defeated would become 1100.  Now here is where it gets a bit confusing.  If player2 goes on to beat player4, player2's elo will go up.  By player2's elo going up, player1's Average_elo_defeated, would also go up.

Comment: you see, when you ask to calculate PID | AVG_ELO_DEF | AVG_ELO_DEF_BY, what does it mean, since each PID has only 1 ELO?

Comment: much more clear now! thanks!

Comment: so PID | AVG_ELO_DEF | AVG_ELO_DEF_BY means "given player PID, gimme the average ELO of all players that won from PID, and gimme the average ELO of all players that have been defeated by PID". Which also means that if PID has no fight yet, AVG_ELO_xxx = 0.

Comment: now, PID is the player, FID is the fighter. One player may play with several fighters. Then, in the row {3,14,13}, winned is the pid or the fid? I only know who won? How will I know the list of people that has been defeated this way?

Comment: or am I missing something again?

Comment: For every 1 fight (FID), there are two players (PID).  One wins and one loses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure there is a better way to do this but here is the answer I came up with.

I created a new view with this query:

```
select  w.fid, w.pid winner, l.pid loser, w.elo winner_elo, l.elo loser_elo
from    (select * from v_fight_review where pid = winner and fid = fid) w,
    (select * from v_fight_review where pid <> winner and fid = fid) l
where w.fid = l.fid;
```

This query gets the elos of every winner and loser for each fight.

I then created two other views.  One view is for the average elos that each opponent has defeated.  The other view is for the average elos of opponents that have defeated them.  Their code is below.

```
--gets the average elo of oppenents that they can beat
create view v_avg_elo_winning as
select p.pid, round(avg(vae.loser_elo), 0) elo
from players p, v_avg_elo vae
where p.pid = vae.winner
group by pid
order by pid;

--gets the average of all of the people that can beat them
create view v_avg_elo_losing as
select p.pid, round(avg(vae.winner_elo), 0) elo
from players p, v_avg_elo vae
where p.pid = vae.loser
group by pid
order by pid;
```

Suggestions are always welcome.